# My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText Isn't Writing All Text

Tags: html, vb.net, visual-studio-2019

So, I am trying to write to a temporary file that is stored in `%LocalAppData%\Temp\EasyHTML\` and the file is called `Preview.html`. I would like it to save everything in the text box called `Code_Export_Code_Box`, which is a RichTextBox.  This is some of the code I tried using

```vb
Try
    'Create Preview File
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\EasyHTML\") = False Then
        MkDir(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\EasyHTML\")
    ElseIf My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\EasyHTML\Preview.html") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\EasyHTML\Preview.html")
    End If
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\EasyHTML\Preview.html", Code_Export_Code_Box.ToString, True)
    'Launch Preview File
    If BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Google Chrome" Then
        Launch.Launch("Google\Chrome\Application", "chrome", "Google Chrome")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Mozilla FireFox" Then
        Launch.Launch("Mozilla Firefox", "firefox", "Mozilla FireFox")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Microsoft Edge" Then
        Launch.Launch("Microsoft\Edge\Application", "msedge", "Microsoft Edge")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Internet Explorer" Then
        Launch.Launch("Internet Explorer", "iexplore", "Internet Explorer")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Opera" Then
        Launch.Launch("Opera", "Launcher", "Opera")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Opera Beta" Then
        Launch.Launch("Opera Beta", "Launcher", "Opera Beta")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Opera Developer" Then
        Launch.Launch("Opera Developer", "Launcher", "Opera Developer")
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error")
End Try
```

`Launch.Launch` is some custom code that allows me to launch a browser without having to paste the same code everytime, so please disregard that.

I expect the sample to look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cool Website</title>





</head>
<body>



</body>
</html>
```

But when I run the "Preview" command to make the preview file, all I get is this:

```html
System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, Text: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Cool Websi...
```

So, what I did to fix my issue was to try to stop the timer called `Timer1` using `Timer1.Stop` before the argument to write the file, but it still ends up with the same result. The code I am currently using is this:

```vb
Try
    Timer1.Stop()
    'Create Preview File
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\EasyHTML\") = False Then
        MkDir(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\EasyHTML\")
    ElseIf My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\EasyHTML\Preview.html") Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\EasyHTML\Preview.html")
    End If
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) & "\Temp\EasyHTML\Preview.html", Code_Export_Code_Box.ToString, True)
    'Launch Preview File
    If BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Google Chrome" Then
        Launch.Launch("Google\Chrome\Application", "chrome", "Google Chrome")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Mozilla FireFox" Then
        Launch.Launch("Mozilla Firefox", "firefox", "Mozilla FireFox")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Microsoft Edge" Then
        Launch.Launch("Microsoft\Edge\Application", "msedge", "Microsoft Edge")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Internet Explorer" Then
        Launch.Launch("Internet Explorer", "iexplore", "Internet Explorer")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Opera" Then
        Launch.Launch("Opera", "Launcher", "Opera")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Opera Beta" Then
        Launch.Launch("Opera Beta", "Launcher", "Opera Beta")
    ElseIf BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem = "Opera Developer" Then
        Launch.Launch("Opera Developer", "Launcher", "Opera Developer")
    End If
    Timer1.Start()
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error")
    Timer1.Start()
End Try
```

I was trying out a bunch of different methods, but this one is one that I found to work the most, so far. But for some reason, the code is not writing all the data I want into `Preview.html`, and it adds `System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox, Text:` at the begining. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Code_Export_Code_Box.ToString()`, you want `Code_Export_Code_Box.Text`. I'd also change some things to avoid those `Exists()` checks, and to avoid repeating the `GetFolderPath()` function all the time. Also, I'd move all those browser conditionals into your custom `Launch()` method, so all you have to do is call it with the string from your combobox.

```vb
Dim path As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) 
path = IO.Path.Combine(path, "Temp", "EasyHTML", "Preview.html")

Try
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path) 
    File.WriteAllText(path, Code_Export_Code_Box.Text)
    Launch.LaunchBrowser(BrowserListing_cmb.SelectedItem, path)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString, "Error")
End Try
```

I want to comment more on my reasoning for removing the `Exists()` checks. For the directory, we have this information in [the documentation of the method I used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory):

> Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path unless they already exist.

Therefore the `Exists()` check adds no new value. Worse, checking first is simply an extra and unnecessary additional trip to the file system, which is about the slowest thing you can do in a computer.

Similarly, we see this in the [documentation for `File.WriteAllText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext):

> If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.

Therefore deleting the file in advance is **two** extra and unnecessary additional trips to the file system: one to see if it's there, and other to delete it. And again, file system access is about the slowest thing you can do in a computer.

---

The proposed `Launch()` methods changes would look like this:

```
'Revision of existing method. 
'Works the same, won't break any other code that needs it.
'Relies on overload shown below
Public Shared Sub Launch(folderpath As String, exe As String, name As String)
    Dim htmlPath As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
    htmlPath = Path.Combine(htmlPath, "Temp", "EasyHTML", "Preview.html")

    Launch(folderpath, exe, name, htmlPath)
End Sub

'New overload of existing method
Public Shared Sub Launch(folderpath As String, exe As String, name As String, argument As String)
    Dim exePath As String = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System))
    exePath = Path.Combine(exePath, "Program Files (x86)", folderpath, exe & ".exe")

    If Not File.Exists(exePath) Then
        exePath = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System))
        exePath = Path.Combine(exePath, "Program Files", folderpath, exe & ".exe")
    End If

    Dim pHelp As New ProcessStartInfo
    pHelp.FileName = Path.Combine(exePath, exe & ".exe")
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(argument) Then pHelp.Arguments = argument
    pHelp.UseShellExecute = True
    pHelp.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
    Dim proc As Process = Process.Start(pHelp)
    Logging.AddLogEntry(name & " Launched")
End Sub


'New method
Public Shared Sub LaunchBrowser(browserName As String, url As String)
    If browserName = "Google Chrome" Then
        Launch("Google\Chrome\Application", "chrome", "Google Chrome", url)
    ElseIf browserName = "Mozilla FireFox" Then
        Launch("Mozilla Firefox", "firefox", "Mozilla FireFox", url)
    ElseIf browserName = "Microsoft Edge" Then
        Launch("Microsoft\Edge\Application", "msedge", "Microsoft Edge", url)
    ElseIf browserName = "Internet Explorer" Then
        Launch("Internet Explorer", "iexplore", "Internet Explorer", url)
    ElseIf browserName = "Opera" Then
        Launch("Opera", "Launcher", "Opera", url)
    ElseIf browserName = "Opera Beta" Then
        Launch("Opera Beta", "Launcher", "Opera Beta", url)
    ElseIf browserName = "Opera Developer" Then
        Launch("Opera Developer", "Launcher", "Opera Developer", url)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer! I managed to get this to work, for the most part. However, I don't think I am able to shrink down the ```Launch.Launch()``` arguments, because of the way how it works. You can view the code here (because I won't fit in the comments box): https://github.com/TheCrafters001/EasyHTML/blob/master/src/EasyHTML/Extra/CustomCommands/Launch.vb

Comment: @TheCrafters001 See my updated answer for how to improve `Launch.Launch()`

Comment: Hi! I am getting a consistent error now. Notably this line catches my attention in the log: "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Log the file path and arguments before calling the function.

Comment: Also, I just noticed the original had three consecutive double quotes: `"""` at the end of the argument string literal. In VB.Net, that would result in one double quote character included with the string in memory. The code I posted to this answer does not include that.